# "Bell" or "Jabotinsky"-matrix - What's the canonical name (if any)? 

Tags: reference-request, matrices, terminology

I'm just reading J. Cigler's script for his talks "Konkrete Analysis" where I find the term "Jabotinsky-matrix" for that matrix, which I've (informally) been taught to call "Bell-matrix" (see at least [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_matrix) where it is subsumed under "Carleman-matrix", but can be found in various papers). Then I find the same in D. Knuth's 1992-article on "[convolution polynomials](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9207221.pdf)" where he develops/refers to that same idea and attributes it to Eri Jabotinsky(1947) *(gives as an example the formal power series for the "half-iterate" of* $ \exp(x)-1$ *)*
(The carleman-matrix is a transpose and similarity-transform using the factorials).

Q: is one of the names "canonized"? And if, which?
Q2: And, if not: which should one prefer in writing?